# Global Variable appearing as local variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following global dictionary

```
global configurationFileInfo_saved
configurationFileInfo_saved = {
        'True_key': 'True',
        'False_key': 'False',
        'filename': "Configuration-noMeta" + extnt,
        'os_key': "os",
        'os': "windows",
        'os_windowsCode': "windows",
        'os_linuxCode': "linux",
        'guiEnabled': 'True',
        'guiEn_key': "GUI",
        'allowCustom': 'True',
        'allowCustom_key': "allowCustomQuizConfiguration",
        'allOrPart': "a",
        'allOrPart_key': "questions_partOrAll",
        'allOrPart_allCode': "a",
        'allOrPart_partCode': "p",
        'questionAmountDivisionFactor': 2,
        'questionAmountDivisionFactor_key': "divisionFactor",
        'mode': "e",
        'mode_key': "mode",
        'mode_noDeduction_code': "noDeductions",
        'mode_allowDeductions_code': "allowDeductions",
        'deductionsPerIncorrect': 1,
        'deductionsPerIncorrect_key': "allowDeductions_pointDeduction_perIncorrectResponse",
        'loc': "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Quizzing Application <Version>\\Admin\\Application Files\\dist\\Main\\",
        'loc_key': "location",
        'title': "Quizzing Appliaction <Version> -- By Geetansh Gautam",
        'title_key': "title"
```

This is where the dictionary is being accessed:

`config_onBoot_keys = list(configSaved(True, False, None).keys())
config_onBoot_vals = list(configSaved(True, False, None).values())`

`configSaved(False, True, configurationFileInfo)`

```
configSaved (Tempoarary function for reading andd writing):

def configSaved(get, save, saveDict):
    if get:
        return configurationFileInfo_saved
    elif save:
        configurationFileInfo_saved = saveDict
```

When I access the dictionary is a function later I get the following error:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'configurationFileInfo_saved' referenced before assignment`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show your actual usage. Ideally your post should include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `global` in the global scope does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because we can only access the global variable inside the function but for modification you have to use the global keyword inside the function.

For example, this will not give the localbound error:

```py
x = 1 # global variable

def example():
    print(x)
example()
```

and this will give the error:

For example:

```py
x = 1 # global variable

def example():
    x = x + 2 # increment x by 2
    print(c)
example()
```

To avoid this error:

```
x = 0 # global variable

def example():
    global x
    x = x + 2 # increment by 2
    print("Inside add():", x)

example()
print("In main:", x)
```

Now the answer to the question:

```
configurationFileInfo_saved = {...}

def configSaved(get, save, saveDict):
    global configurationFileInfo_saved
    if get:
        return configurationFileInfo_saved
    elif save:
        configurationFileInfo_saved = saveDict
```

Comment: This looks really wrong to me. Can you show how having the global statement outside of the function produces an `UnboundLocalError` exception?

Comment: @jordanm it doesn't. But the OP seems to be using the global statement in the global scope expecting that to mean that a variable is global everywhere.  They then "use it in a function", of course, they haven't shown that and they must provide a [mcve]. In which case, likely the OP needs to use a global declaration in the function. Or better yet **not rely on global mutable state**

Comment: @jordanm I have added some examples to address your concern. Please let me know if its still wrong, i will remove the answer and read more about it. :)

Comment: The global variable is declared outside of all functions. I meant that I cannot access the variable in any function.

Comment: You can access it but cannot modify it.

Comment: @GeetanshG Can you add any function where you are using the variable?

Comment: @ParthS007 I added it to the question

Comment: @GeetanshG I have updated the answer in reference to your function. Can you check it?

Comment: @ParthS007 that code did not work, but putting the global declaration at the very beginning of the function did the trick!

Comment: @GeetanshG Updated once again, If I helped you in moving forward, you can upvote/accept the answer. Thanks :)